# IORA-00904: Invalid Identifier when converting Radians to Degrees

Tags: oracle-12c

I am using this simple query in Oracle SQL Developer to basically convert a value in Radians to Degrees but I get error at the function itself.

`SELECT Degrees(1.571) as ANGLE FROM DUAL;`

> Error: Ora-00904: "DEGREES": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

I checked Oracle documentation and a function called `DEGREES` does exist. I tried changing the query to convert `DEGREES` to `RADIANS` but same error.

Can someone please advise what's wrong here? The database I am connecting to is Oracle 12cR1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Post the link to the documentation you checked

Answer (score 1):

The DEGREES function you refer to is not in the Oracle database code.  It is in the [JavaDB](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/) which is also known as Derby.  There is a construct in MySQL called [DEGREES](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-degrees-function.php) so this may be what you were thinking of.

You can make your own function like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION radians_to_degree(p_radian IN NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
   RETURN p_radian * 0.0174533;
END radians_to_degree;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I were to convert a column value which is in Radians to Degrees, is there an easier way than having to use above function?

Comment: @DK2014 just use radian * 0.0174533

Comment: thanks. I tried multiplying my radian value (1.571) which actually represents 90Deg, with * 0.0174533 but then it becomes small. But when I divide it then I get 90.01163103825637558513289750362395650106.